Multiple issues - how to get compensated?
I was booked on a flight from PBI > PHL > LHR.  Ticketed as AA2071/AA728 sold as BA4782/BA1587 on 8/10/2024.  There was a 2 hour layover in PHL, but announcements were made twice regarding three 2 hour delays (total 6 hours) - after waiting 7 hours in the airport at 2am the flight was canceled.  (This was due to crew scheduling, not equipment or weather)
This cascaded into many problems:

When I left the airport at 3am, I was told I would be booked on the same flight the next day 8/11/24, however, I noticed in BA app that I was booked on a flight the following day 8/12/2024.  I had my travel agent rebook me on the flight I was told I would be on.
My luggage was sent the following day 8/12/2024 - I did not receive my 3 bags until 31 day after I checked them.  (baggage was damaged)
The delay caused me to miss a non-refundable night's hotel stay and West End theatre tickets.
My luggage
I did make the 8-day cruise that departed on 8/12/24 I booked from Southampton with no luggage.

I had travel insurance for the trip and submitted claims to British Airways and my travel insurance for both issues (cancellation and lost luggage) - but for 3 weeks had no response from airlines or insurance (brining us to today).
Who is responsible for restitution?  I have saved all the baggage flight stickers and can see that each bag was sent to different countries by both AA and BA.
I know the airlines will pay for my night stay in PHL; hotel, food, and sundries.
I believe it is British Airways who is responsible for paying for clothing and toiletries purchased while on vacation.
My insurance will cover the cost of the lost hotel/theatre in London.
Am I due any restitution from the airlines for canceling the flight and the delays?  Is there monetary compensation or travel vouchers due?  Which airline should pay?
Should I submit all expenses to both airlines and travel insurance?  How much can I expect to be reimbursed? (Of course, I have all the receipts).  I did get an email from insurance asking for proof of cancellation - how can I provide this?

I believe it is British Airways who is responsible for paying for clothing and toiletries purchased while on vacation - why? The flight was operated by AA.

@littleadv but the contract is with BA, isn't it?  Practically speaking, though, the important question isn't so much "who is liable" as it is "to whom should I submit the claim?"

You have a travel insurance, so go to it. If airlines should compensate, they ask directly or they tell you how/where to ask (so they must compensate less). -- Compensation for clothing and toiletries: nearly nothing from airlines (my estimates: less then 50$ if you are lucky).

@phoog by that logic why not the travel agent? The operating airline is responsible

Since the flight was operated by AA, you are not eligible for EC261, so no compensation for the delay. What remains is the Montreal Convention. See https://www.forbes.com/advisor/credit-cards/travel-rewards/montreal-convention-luggage/ for a good overview.
